# Extracting a string from another string Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this particular string :

**TOYIN KEMIOGS/OYO/2277TGOGSLAGOS**

from this string containing 2 '/'

I want it to extract from wherever we have **OGS** and stop at wherever we have **OGS**. **OGS** always start and end my extracted string

I want an extracted result like this

**OGS/OYO/2277TGOGS**

Thanks so much

Comment: You could use `String.includes()` or `String.indexOf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it but as a string between first occurrence and last occurrence of OGS as follows:

```
var a = 'TOYIN KEMIOGS/OYO/2277TGOGSLAGOS';
console.log(a.slice(a.indexOf("OGS"),a.lastIndexOf("OGS")) +"OGS");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method of string to extract the data required.

```js
const str = "TOYIN KEMIOGS/OYO/2277TGOGSLAGOS";
const result = str.match(/OGS.*OGS/); // Its greedy in nature so you can also use /OGS.*?OGS/
console.log(result[0]);
```

Comment: match will restrict it with first and second occurrence of 'OGS' Is there any trick with match to over come it ?

Comment: @HarshitDewan It is for first and the last, since `.*` is greedy it will look up to end and then backtrack to match the last `OGS`.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the start/stop sequences as non-matching groups:

```js
const str = 'TOYIN KEMIOGS/OYO/2277TGOGSLAGOS';
const [match] = str.match(/(?:OGS).+(?:OGS)/);

console.log(match); // "OGS/OYO/2277TGOGS"
```

---

If you don't want to keep the start/stop sequences (`"OGS"`), you can treat them as positive lookbehind/lookaheads:

```js
const str = 'TOYIN KEMIOGS/OYO/2277TGOGSLAGOS';
const [match] = str.match(/(?<=OGS).+(?=OGS)/);

console.log(match); // "/OYO/2277TG"
```

Here is a string manipulation version, which captures the first and last index.

```js
const extractBetween = (str, marker) =>
  str.slice(str.indexOf(marker),
    str.lastIndexOf(marker) + marker.length);

const str = 'TOYIN KEMIOGS/OYO/2277TGOGSLAGOS';
const match = extractBetween(str, 'OGS');

console.log(match); // "OGS/OYO/2277TGOGS"
```

Comment: Output doesn't matches required result. Also match will restrict it with first and second occurrence of OGS. is there any trick with match to over come it ?

Comment: @HarshitDewan my code works fine. I just put the wrong output in the comment.

Comment: Output of your code is `/OYO/2277TG` only! I tried it out in my local. But thats not my ask. My ask is match will only look for 1st and 2nd occurrence, what if there is any third occurrence of string? is there any way to handle. it with match?

Comment: @HarshitDewan That is if you want to leave them out. It is an alternative answer. The first snippet is my actual answer to the question... Anyways, I added a modified version of your example; which I turned into a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = "TOYIN KEMIOGS/OYO/2277TGOGSLAGOS";
let phrase = "OGS";
let start = str.indexOf(phrase);
let end = str.lastIndexOf(phrase) + phrase.length;

let newStr = str.slice(start, end);
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.